# When are TIMER0, TIMER1 & TIMER2 events triggered?

Tags: python

Documentation is sparse [on these event types](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.4/bpy_types_enum_items/event_type_items.html).  I also could not find code examples that receive these event types and do something with it.  What are these event types for?

Comment: I think it relates to this https://docs.blender.org/api/3.4/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.event_timer_add and that https://docs.blender.org/api/3.4/bpy.types.Timer.html but no idea how

Comment: The source code says `TIMER0 = 0x0111,  /* Timer event, slot for internal use (273). */`, so I don't think you will ever see them in python API events...